# Mako calling function from string?

Tags: python, mako

Is there an easy way to call a function given a string name in mako?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to look it up in the dict returned by `globals()`. Eg.:

```
<$ func_name = 'my_function_name' %>
${globals()[func_name](...)}
```

Although, this does smell rather nasty to me. If you could expand upon your end game perhaps we can figure out something a bit saner.

Comment: thanks, this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842458/python-lookup-function so i'm trying to figure out ways around it

Comment: I like your interrobang. Also, +1 for a good answer and for getting clarification on why this is needed.